# Checking Proof for the following Divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, divisibility

> Prove that for every natural number $n\ge 2$, $n$ does not divide
>   $n+1$.

Proof: Suppose for every natural number $n\ge 2$, $n$ does divide $n+1.$ However, for natural numbers $a$ and $b,$ $a$ divides $b$ or goes into $b$ if $b=ka$ for some natural number $k \ge 2$. Thus, there is only some $n$ that divides $n+1.$ Therefore, this is a contradiction.

Comment: What is the contradiction, exactly? I can imagine where it's going, but it's best to spell it out explicitly.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer that there is some n that divides n+1 but it is assumed every natural number ≥2 divides n+1.

Comment: Your assumption should be, "Suppose there exists **a** natural number $n_0\geq2$ such that $n_0\mid n_0+1$."

Answer (score 3):

A direct proof seems to be easier. If $n\geq 1$ divides $n+1$ then $n$ divides also the difference $n+1-n=1$ (note that $n$ divides $n$) which implies that $n=1$.

You may also say. If $n\geq 2$ divides $n+1$ then $n$ divides also the difference $n+1-n=1$ (note that $n$ divides $n$) which implies that $n=1$. Contradiction.

Comment: but aren't we assuming ≥2?

Comment: @k.rudin See my edit.